# Faster computer after removing and reinserting ram

Tags: memory

I have an old piece of junk laptop (eee900hd) that lags on basically everything. I opened up the laptop and removed the ram. Several hours later, I reinserted it, booted up the computer, and it ran at least 50% faster. Why did this happen?

Comment: The placebo effect? What OS? What are the full system specs?

Comment: fedora 20, celeron 550,1 gb ram, no integrated graphics or gpu

Comment: How did you measure the 50% performance increase? Any benchmarks? There is a possibility that moving the memory might have caused some other component to make slightly better connection, say a heatsink making slightly better connection and so making the computer run longer before thermal throttling. I doubt that just reseatig the RAM could cause a significant boost

Comment: I didn't do any benchmarks before or after, I just know that my computer usually takes 5-6 seconds to open the activities tab in fedora, this time it took 1 second. There aren't any components located next to the ram.

Comment: Sorry, but the *no integrated graphics or gpu* - unless this was mistake - gives me no confidence you actually know what you're talking about. So, without further *evidence* that what you're reporting actually happened, Hitchens razor.

Comment: It confused me too- I looked my cpu up online and most sources either don't have any info on its integrated graphics or say it doesn't exist.